# Qt do shallow copy while selecting from SQLite Memory Database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, memory

Is there any possibility to do a shallow copy of the contents stored in an SQLite Memory Database?

Qt provides (in interconnection with SQLite) the possibility to operate with the SQLite DB on memory level; however while selecting rows the data is normally copied the deep way (this is however needed for non memory databases).
The main problem is by doing a deep copy of the data which is already stored in the memory I would have the memory consumption doubled - however it would be great to avoid this doubled consumption, otherwise the approach for any in-memory DB seems quite useless since i cannot do anything specific with data stored as char* in my memory.

Is there a shallow way to get from char* to QVariant* without having to copy the already existing data? Possibly subclass QSqlRecord or overwrite the sqlite driver!?

The result should be that i am able to use SQLite in memory DB the same way i would use Qt's "standard" container classes (like QMap, QHash, QList, ...) consisting of shallow copies of the "original data" - so that i am able to pass these shallow copied objects / object structures to other classes like QStandardItem to make them visible in a QTableView for example.

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing much to do with Qt, since it's sqlite that doesn't provide this functionality. You'd need to access the data in sqlite's database representation directly. As this memory can get moved about at any time, any pointers that you would get would only be valid until the next SQL command.

If you were to do it, you would need to modify sqlite to expose direct access to in-memory database representation of data.

Alas, I think you have a case of premature optimization. When Qt is accessing the database, it doesn't copy all of the database's contents, merely the results of the running query. This will only "double" the memory use if you were to query all of the tables of the database, in their entirety. If you do so, you have bigger problems as such design leads to very bad user experience.

Comment: "When Qt is accessing the database, it doesn't copy all of the database's contents, merely the results of the running query" - however this is what i meant...In General (with a "normal") DB the approach would be to select data and provide it for example to QStandardItem/StandardItemModel and display it - however if the approach would be to visualize nearly everything of the in-memory database the memory would be doubled (often you cannot avoid displaying "huge" amounts of data)

Comment: @shockzZ Just think about the numbers here. Think of how many pixels there are on your screen. There's no problem fitting 32 bits per pixel in your memory. Now think of how many pixels one needs per one letter of text. Filling all of the screen with even small letters requires less storage than the screen bitmap takes. Now let's recall that you can set things up so that only the *visible* items are retained in memory. Even if you have the **horrendously bad** user interface that lets you scroll through millions of items (it's next to unusable), you don't need them all present in memory twice.

Comment: @shockzZ "the approach would be to select data and provide it for example to QStandardItem/StandardItemModel and display it" Well, if you do it this way it's you who is messing things up, not Qt :) The approach is to use a `QSqlTableModel` or `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. Those are only keeping a small item cache in memory and they query the database as the view requests new data.

Comment: @shockzZ I think you've fallen into the trap of seeing a problem that's entirely linked to your presumed solution **but failing to let us know first what solution you've chosen**. Once you select the correct approach, the problem disappears. And the correct approach is either to use `QSqlXxxxModel` or to roll your own model that queries the database for each `data` and `setData`.

Comment: Sure - i know all that stuff, and I know SqlRelationalTableModel or QSqlTableModel; however it depends on the use case which to choose and sometimes it makes more sense to use QStandardItemModel or a self written model for a specific use case. However: This was just an example - the sense was not to discuss all various models Qt provides, i just came up with an example; but you're right - in this case with a memory DB QSqlXXXXXModel makes sense, since it's the RAM you are stressing, but this is not what i want to do...

Comment: The point is when you use it that way you described, then it is more related to the choosen storage medium (RAM / HDD), what i wanted is a small layer in between. Place SQLite "Container engine to SSD" with "slower" R/W speeds, or place it in the RAM if there is enough which allows faster R/W speeds - in combination with a shared memory space or additional TCP/IP interface you would be able to view each table very comfortable during debugging and it's much more convinient for bigger datastructures than placing one container into another one; however this approch is senseless by "doubling" ram

Comment: @shockzZ OK, now I really don't know what you're after, and I'm not sure you do either. Initially it looked as if you wanted to have access to the *values* stored into the relational columns in an in-memory SQLite database. Now you're talking of SSDs and TCP/IP.

Comment: @shockzZ "it's the RAM you are stressing" Look, **you** decided to use an in-memory Sqlite database, not me :) With a properly written model, there's *no* data duplication, save for what's visible on the screen + a small cache that you can set to zero. This is true  whether the database lives in RAM or on a server on the moon. I don't know what else do you want.

Comment: @shockzZ since you mention `QStandardItemModel`, note that it is a swiss-army-knife jack-of-all-trades convenience model which can do everything, but nothing well. Use it only for relatively small amounts of data or for prototyping before writing a more optimal custom model. Here you are worried about memory use, so `QSIM` doesn't belong to this discussion.

Comment: @hyde; you're right (Kuba Ober is right as well), but these are all comments that i am already aware of, QSIM was designed to handle all kinds of represantations via a view - however as you said it's not the fastest and furthermore not designed to "stay in code forever", it was designed for rapid prototyping and in production code you/me/we should use custom written models for specific implementations.
However, this was not the point of my question, it was just an example and still a valid one, even if it should be replaced later.
The question is more about shallow/deep copy than any models

Comment: @shockzZ There's no way to shallow-copy data from sqlite without changing sqlite code. That's your answer. Is there anything else you wish to know?